# Slow performance after upgrade to Windows 11

Tags: laptop, performance, windows-10-upgrade, windows-11

After upgrading to Windows 11, my cursor is sometimes frozen and if I am able to see which task is occupying more recourse, it is the HP UWP service that handles the keyboard functions (such as fn). I am using an HP laptop.

Any suggestion to fix the issue?

[image]

Comment: Windows 11 isn’t going to be properly released until 2023. It’s still in development. Right now Microsoft is just beta testing it. I wouldn’t upgrade now because you can’t be assured that your drivers will work properly with good functionality, compatibility and performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue
The probleme is in the recent update hp driver rool up via optional update windows

Temporary fix : change service behavior to disable or delay

Comment: “hp driver rool up” - What?

Comment: Can you add more information to your explanation using maybe images or hyperlinks?

Comment: I changed the startup of the "HP hotkey uwp service" to Disabled and that seems to have temporarily fixed the issue. (Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services)

Comment: this temporary workaround seems like working, however with disabling the service you obviously cannot use it anymore. I expected the hotkeys on the keyboard won't work after this modification but they are working fine, so I wonder what type of functionality I loss with this modification.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 11 badly supports your hardware, I suggest to rollback to
Windows 10. Note that you can only rollback within 10 days,
afterward the rollback is impossible.

I also suggest to wait at least 6 months before trying again to upgrade
to Windows 11, in the hope that the problem will be fixed.

Comment: From the downvote I understand that this is not the advice you're looking for. However, we're not Microsoft developers here and cannot fix Windows. It's a fact that Windows 11 was released much too soon and suffers from a lot of problems. For a stable system, returning to Windows 10 is the best advice I (or anyone) can give.

Comment: As @harrymc and debest stated, Windows 11 is a work-in-progress. It's kind of you to be a *Beta* tester, but don;t expect it to compare to a fully-tested OS.

Comment: @harrymc - You originally state 10 days then you day 28 days. The default amount of days for a rollback is 10 days.  So where is the 28 days coming from? It’s possible to extend the date but that’s a separate issue.

Comment: @Ramhound: You're right - Microsoft has changed the rules. Again.